# having Issues connecting to quickbooks online via IPP and .net devkit

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to connect to QB online and I am having issues.  I have created a demo account for QBO and added my test app to the account and granted access for my app.  I have my consumer key and secret tokens.  I have installed the .net devkit and have my test project setup.

I am using the code example from here...

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/0299_Synchronous_Calls/0001_Data_Service_APIs

everything works until I call the add method to create a customer.  the same goes for anything else I try to do as far as adding data.

This is the error I get...

"message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401; source=OAuthStrategy; oauth_problem=token_rejected; cause=net.oauth.OAuthProblemException: token_rejected"

It says token rejected so I am unclear as to what I am missing.  These are the tokens given to me in the online app section.

here is my code..

```
        Dim AccessToken As String = [redacted]
        Dim AccessTokenSecret As String = [redacted]

        Dim ConsumerKey As String = [redacted]
        Dim ConsumerSecret As String = [redacted]

        Dim OAuthValidator As OAuthRequestValidator = New OAuthRequestValidator(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret)
        Dim Context As ServiceContext = New ServiceContext(OAuthValidator, RealmID, IntuitServicesType.QBD)

        Dim dataServices As DataServices = New DataServices(Context)

        Dim qbdCustomer As Customer = New Customer()
        With qbdCustomer
            qbdCustomer.Name = "My New Customer"
            qbdCustomer.GivenName = "New Customer"
            qbdCustomer.FamilyName = "New Customer"
        End With
        Dim customerAdded As Customer = dataServices.Add(qbdCustomer)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to connect to QBO, you are using the wrong entities.

You should be using QBO and NOT QBD.

Also, your InitializeServiceContext looks like it is missing some parameters.

Comment: OK. I changed it to qbo and added the only other param and now it immediately throws an error "unauthorized" at the serviceContext line... Dim Context As ServiceContext = New ServiceContext(OAuthValidator, AppToken, RealmID, IntuitServicesType.QBO)

Comment: Are you going through the Oauth flow and getting an access token ?